# If I have a ThingFactory which creates multiple concrete IThings, each with exclusive parameters, how do I avoid ThingFactory knowing about them all?

Tags: design-patterns, factory

A common problem I run into is when I have a Factory (let's say ThingFactory) which creates multiple different IThing implementations, and each of these concrete implementation classes requires an exclusive set of constructor parameters.

With a naïve implementation of the ThingFactory, it would need to know about the union of all these parameters, which seems like a code smell.  How might I be able to instantiate multiple implementations of an object without requiring an all-knowing ThingFactory?

Comment: The entire point of a factory is that it knows about the gory details of all subclasses, so that its callers don't have to.

Comment: Start by looking into why you need the factory in the first place. If you have to pass all those class-specific parameters anyway, why not just call the constructors directly?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Consider a command-line application which can take a bunch of different parameters. One represents the type of IThing object to create, and the remaining are specific arguments for that particular type (connection strings, file paths, whatever). Some code needs to instantiate the proper type and pass the context-specific parameters.  This sounds an awful lot like a Factory to me.

Comment: @KilianFoth If you think it's alright to have a Factory class that is aware of different types of login credentials plus specific API parameters plus relevant file paths, etc., then perhaps we just have different ideas about clean code. I think a cleaner option would be to have each class take in an IOptions object, which is created with its own factory from command-line parameters (for example). This would unfortunately make a cast required in each consuming IThingFactory class, but it seems like less of a code smell than a convoluted factory with a very long list of parameters.

Comment: You should put what you described in your reply to me in the question itself, this is relevant information; the term "Factory" encompasses a number of roughly related but different creational patterns, and what you just said excludes some of them, so that's helpful for people who might want to write an answer.

Comment: I do not see your problem. All you need to make sure your `Things` have a constructor taking a `Bag of parameters` and pick the ones needed. So you call your factory with this `Bag` and get a proper initialized `Thing` back.

Comment: @ThomasJunk I am converging on a solution similar to the "bag of parameters", but I don't think each class should know how to create its dependencies based on string parameters, for example.  So instead I'd abstract the creation of different concrete parameter "bags" (IOptions implementations, let's say).  But same idea, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "Factory" encompasses a number of roughly related but different creational patterns (both formally described and informal), so it's important to clarify what you mean when you say you have "a factory".

Some of these are "custom constructor" kind of factories (like a static method that helps convey extra semantics via it's name, or does some work that's not appropriate or convenient for the constructor). Some of these factories are objects that let you partially initialize an instance, so that you can pass them around to complete the initialization process later. Some factories manage families of related objects in an abstract way.

What you have, although arguably a kind of a factory, isn't exactly any of the above. You wrote:

> Consider a command-line application which can take a bunch of different parameters. One represents the type of IThing object to create, and the remaining are specific arguments for that particular type (connection strings, file paths, whatever). Some code needs to instantiate the proper type and pass the context-specific parameters.

The fact that the input here is coming from the outside of the program itself is an important detail. You have two concerns here: parsing the input, and instantiating the relevant objects. Your factory has to figure out which concrete class to instantiate - there's no way around that - but it doesn't have to *understand* the parameters; it's probably more manageable if you delegate that responsibility elsewhere.

What you could do is confine the knowledge about the parameters (and the logic to parse them) to the concrete classes themselves (or to some code closely associated with each class). E.g. have a static ("custom constructor") factory function on each class that accepts the raw string parameters (e.g. as a list, or as a dictionary of key-value pairs, if your raw input is keyword-based, and not positional). Each of the factory functions would accept these in the same format - you'd have a unified representation. You have to put the code that parses these parameters *somewhere* anyway, you might as well place it there. In some sense, each of these would be like a mini entry point to a small program; a mini `main()`, if you will, except that it produces an instance. It's basically the old divide and conquer strategy: you don't have to solve the entire problem in one place.

Then just have your main factory identify which of these factory methods to call, and pass the rest of the parameters in this unified format. Beyond knowing how to extract them from the raw collection of program arguments (a command-line argument parsing library can make this easier), your top-level factory doesn't have to understand or know anything else about these parameters. Your main factory just needs to deal with the string that identifies the concrete type.

You can implement this identification logic in several different ways. First, you could hardcode it (bunch of if-s, a switch statement). Here, you can make it so that the code is aware of each of the concrete types, so in general, the classes wouldn't have to implement the shared IThing interface (although they might need to do so in your particular case - you haven't provided enough details).

You can go for a dictionary-driven approach, like in Ewan's [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/439225/275536), which lets you update the top-level factory more simply and concisely when you need to, or, if you have reflection capabilities, you could make use of that (perhaps coupled with a naming convention for your concrete factory functions) to make your main factory completely generic. But be careful there, as with any external input.
Here, you'd have to rely on some common `IThing` interface with a set of abstract methods that make sense at the entry point of your application (like `Run()`).

P.S. Not sure if your command-line scenario was just a motivating example for a more general problem, but when it comes to command-line apps, also consider the possibility that maybe such an application could be split into several different, smaller and more focused command-line tools, that wouldn't have to manage this complex instantiation logic internally.

Comment: Thank you, I very much like the idea of separating the code which "converts command-line parameters to concrete dependencies" from the classes which consume these dependencies (i.e. each IThing implementation shouldn't need to know how to parse text input and convert it to concrete dependencies).

And yes, the command-line example is the actual example in my case.  It needs to pull data from a data source, but depending on the type of data source, different parameters will be needed (i.e. if it's a file, a file path is needed; if a cloud service, an API key will be needed, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

In general, yes, the factory itself does need to know about all the parameters. However, that doesn't mean that the public interface of your factory needs to expose all those parameters. To take a made up example:

```
enum WidgetType { Sliding, Spinning };

class WidgetFactory
{
  public IWidget Create(WidgetType type, Color c)
  {
    switch (type)
    {
      case WidgetType.Sliding:
        return new SlidingWidget(c, slideDistance: 10)

      case WidgetType.Spinning:
        return new SpinningWidget(c, rpm: 60)
    }
  }
}
```

The consumers of your factory are now insulated from the details of how to create each type of widget.

Comment: Yes, this is how I need to create factories now.  Unfortunately, if each Factory requires different types of login tokens, file paths, database connection strings, etc., then the factory which creates them all becomes a cumbersome mess of different concepts.

Comment: A factory (or any other design pattern) isn't magically going to make complexity in your business logic go away.

Comment: `f each Factory requires different types of login tokens, file paths, database connection strings, etc., then the factory which creates them all becomes a cumbersome mess of different concepts` then your factory is not absolutely abstracted. As you might guess, you need more levels of abstractions like input parameters. But bear in mind that Factories are somewhat a composition root. It's not like SOLID matters in these cases. They hold all the "dirty" code/coupling you don't want to be scattered all over the source code. In certain components, SOLID is useless and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Dictionary of IThingFactories

```
CompositeThingFactory : IThingFactory
{
   private Dictionary<string,IThingFactory> factories

   public Create(string type)
   {
       return this.factories[type].Create(type);
   }

   public Register(string key, IThingFactory fac)
   {
       this.factories.Add(key, fac)
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems to kick the proverbial can down the road.  At some point I still need to populate this dictionary, which means some object needs to know about all the different parameters that are required to instantiate all the different types of factories.

Comment: you can use unity xml config, or LoadAssembly to populate them if you want. but "my program needs to reference the classes it uses" isnt a big problem in my book

Comment: My program referencing the classes it uses isn't the problem; "a single class referencing the union of all the context-specific parameters for all concrete implementations of an interface" is the problem.

If I use an XML config, etc., this doesn't seem to solve the problem, it just relies on the same parameters in a different format.

Comment: your top level program/app/main class has to know about all the other classes. Unless you load dlls at runtime in a kind of plugin approach as suggested theres no way around that. The coupledness you want to avoid is one Thing knowing about other Things

Comment: this approach also saves you having to edit ThingFactory to add more things when only one program needs those new things